# Logging during powershell string find and replace

Tags: powershell, replace, find

My goal is to be able to log what I'm changing with a find/replace script in powershell.

This works for a replace:

```
$Content | ForEach-Object {$_ -Replace $oldIP2, $newIP} | Set-Content $file.PSPath
```

However, if I add an if statement so I can add something to the log the `-replace` empties the file except for the replacement.

```
$Content | ForEach-Object {
        if($_ -match $oldIP1) { 
                #logging stuff would go here
                $_ -Replace $oldIP1, $newIP
        }
    } | Set-Content $file.PSPath
```

so a file like:

> 1.1.1.1  ($oldIP1)
>
> asd asd 
>   asd asd
>
> asd

turns in to

> 123.123.123.123  ($newIP)

My understanding was that $_ becomes each line in $Content, and is replaced per-line.  Where is the rest of my content going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are dumping your other content in the ForEach loop.

Let's break it down by section of your pipeline. In your example it reads the first line, and passes it to the ForEach loop. That says if it matches the `$oldIP1` variable, then it replaces the `$oldIP1` string with the `$newIP` string. That gets passed down the pipe to Set-Content, which collects the string, and waits for the rest of the info from the pipe.

Now it moves to the second line, and passes that to the `ForEach` loop, which checks to see if that line matches the `$oldIP1` variable. It does not match it, so the `ForEach` line does nothing. It doesn't pass the data down, it simply does nothing.

Next it sends the third line to the `ForEach` loop, which again checks to see if it matches the `$oldIP1` variable, which it does not, so it again does nothing.

The only thing that was passed down to the `Set-Content` cmdlet was the first line that did match the qualifying statement in the `If` statement. So that's all that is written

Now, the `-replace` will only replace the text if it is found, so the `If` statement there is useless, since if it doesn't find `$oldIP1` in the current line, it can't replace it, and it just passes the text along down the pipeline unchanged. Remove the `If`, and you get your expected output. Or change it to:

```
if($_ -match $oldIP1) { 
            #logging stuff would go here
            $_ -Replace $oldIP1, $newIP
    }Else{$_}
```

That way if it doesn't find the IP in the line, it just passes the line along unchanged and skips the logging.

Comment: I KNEW it had to be something with my handling of the piping in that if statement.  That got it nailed immediately.  Thanks very much.  Marked as answered in record time!